# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error when calling from one domain to another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error when I am calling from one domain of test page function to another domain of html page using java script
`  in order.html page i wrote script function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Test();
    }
    );
    function Test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8',
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            jsonp: false,              
            url: 'http://localhost:27746/Test.aspx/SessionLogin',                
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                 
            }
        });
    }`
```

`It's not going to sessionlogin() function break point. after page
 load is completed I am getting the error. Even test.aspx page doesnot
 have any controls it has only sessionlogin() in .cs`

Comment: I would assume there's an error on `http://localhost:27746/Test.aspx/SessionLogin`. what's it returning?

Comment: public  void SessionLogin()
    { 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string callback = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(callback + "({[ \"name\": nalini, \"initial\": g]})");

    }  Even i am not getting break point for this function. After page load completed I am getting this issue. Even though i don't have any aspx page controls. just in .cs i defined this function only

Comment: I got this solution by removing  all code of Test.aspx design page. even t<html> tags also